# List Facebook users that I follow but that are not friends

Tags: facebook

How can I list the Facebook users that I follow, but they are not friends with me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done this a few weeks ago, it is pretty simple:

- Go to your profile
- Select *Friends* below your cover photo
- Select *Following*

If you don't see *Following*, it means you're not following anyone yet.

You can find the reference over **[here](https://www.facebook.com/help/193340950731305)**.